# Present Value Calculation Field

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm trying to create a Calculation field in Cognito Forms to return the Present Value of a future sum of money.  In other words, if I have 1 million dollars in 30 years, what is the Present Value of that 1 million dollars today.

The formula for calculating the PV function is:

PV=FV(1/(1+r)ª

where

PV=Present Value
FV=Future Value
r=Rate of Return (%)
ª=Term (number of years in the future)

My question is how do I express this formula in a Cognito Forms Calculation Field?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

This calculation is a bit tricky as you have to set it up a bit out of order to get the power set on the correct number.

I was able to set this up with the following 4 fields on my demo form, that I will be included a link to at the end of this post.

The Future Value is set as a Number field with the type of Integer.

The Rate of Return is set as a Number field with the type of Percent.

The Term is set as a Number field with the type of Integer.

The Present Value is the Calculation field where you will build the calculation and this will provide out answer. The type of this field is set to Number. The following is the calculation I used, that references the other fields on the form.

```
=(FutureValue) * Math.Pow((1/(1+RateOfReturn)), Term)
```

As you can see we have to apply the Math.Pow around the second half of the calculation as we do not want the Future Value to be included in the power part of the equation. You can learn more about Math.Pow in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/50/calculations/numeric-calculations) on number calculations.

To see this form in action you can use the following public link, and test out your own values.

https://www.cognitoforms.com/CognitoFormsTestAccount/PresentValueCalculation

You can also copy my demo into your own Organization and continue to build on what I have already started by using the following template link.

https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates/shared/CognitoFormsTestAccount/PresentValueCalculation

Comment: Also, do you have a similar calculation for Future Value?  We take a present sum of money and value it after a term in the future?